# installation of kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.3.0.Final-wildfly8

Tags: drools, wildfly, workbench, kie

I am trying to deploy "kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.3.0.Final-wildfly8" on WildFly 9.1 in standalone mode while starting(enable ) of this am getting following stack trace. Please find the attachment of screen shot of error and server log

```
ERROR [org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders] (MSC service thread 1-4) Can't initialize FileSystemProviders: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.uberfire.java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider: Provider org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.buildProviders(FileSystemProviders.java:65)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.setup(FileSystemProviders.java:48)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.resolveProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:104)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83)
    at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:241)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:252)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:187)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.FileSystem$1366014920$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.buildPath(SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.java:33)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserCachePersistence.<init>(SocialUserCachePersistence.java:42)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserInstancePersistence.<init>(SocialUserInstancePersistence.java:16)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:306)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:262)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:447)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:94)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.uberfire.java.nio.IOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to open server socket for /127.0.0.1:9418
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.buildAndStartDaemon(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:508)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:374)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:343)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 63 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to open server socket for /127.0.0.1:9418
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.daemon.git.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:197)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.buildAndStartDaemon(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:506)
    ... 71 more

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.java:110)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.daemon.git.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:195)
    ... 72 more

2015-10-10 12:22:55,911 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-7) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.3.0.Final-wildfly8.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:

{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.3.0.Final-wildfly8.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.3.0.Final-wildfly8.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service

    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup() on org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer@432ba935
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:143)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:306)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:262)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:447)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:94)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
    ... 37 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.getProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:114)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.resolveProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:107)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83)
    at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:241)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:252)
    at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:187)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.FileSystem$1366014920$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.buildPath(SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.java:33)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserCachePersistence.<init>(SocialUserCachePersistence.java:42)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserInstancePersistence.<init>(SocialUserInstancePersistence.java:16)
    at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:76)

    ... 42 more
```

Comment: See [this jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UF-275) for a solution (and vote for it).